# Removing connection between each section of data in a plot: MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

As seen on the figure below, I have a collection of data from different time sets. However, there is a line connecting the end of each data section to the start of the next.

Is there any way of suppressing this connection without altering the data?

[image]

Comment: You need to bin your data. Please see: [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

#### Intro

Currently MATLAB is drawing lines between all consecutive points in your arrays, including when there is a big jump in `x` value.

An equivalent example would be this plot:

```
% Create some x with points spaced by 0.1, except at 2 jumps of 5
x = [0:0.1:10, 15:0.1:25, 30:0.1:40];
y = sin(x);
plot(x,y)
```

[image: joined]

Notice the straight line joins between our 3 sections (10-15, 25-30).

---

#### Method 1: hold on for multiple plots

We can use the `find` and `diff` to get the regions where `x` jumps, and then plot each region individually.

```
% Include indices for the first (we're going to +1, so start at 0) and last elements
% You can change this 1 to any tolerance you like, it might be of the order 10^4 for you!
idx = [0, find(diff(x) > 1), numel(x)];
% Hold on for multiple plots
hold on;
% Loop over sections and plot
for ii = 2:numel(idx)
    % Plots will loop through colours if you don't specify one, specified blue ('b') here
    plot(x(idx(ii-1)+1:idx(ii)), y(idx(ii-1)+1:idx(ii)), 'b')
end
hold off; % good practise so you don't accidentally plot more on this fig!
```

[image: not joined]

---

#### Method 2: using `NaN`

You could use also use `NaN` values to break up your data. `NaN` values aren't plotted by MATLAB, so if we include one in each break, there will be nothing to connect the line to and we'll see a break:

```
% Notice the NaNs!
x = [0:0.1:10, NaN, 15:0.1:25, NaN, 30:0.1:40];
y = sin(x);
plot(x,y)
```

[image: not joined]

**Automation**: You may want to use the `diff` function to find these jumps on the fly for some pre-existing `x`, like so

```
% Define some x and y as before, without NaNs, with big gaps in x
x = [0:0.1:10, 15:0.1:25, 30:0.1:40];
y = sin(x);
% Create anonymous function to insert NaN at vector index 'n'
insertNaN = @(v, n) [v(1:n), NaN, v(n+1:end)];
% Get indices where gap is bigger than some value (in this case 1)
idx = find(diff(x) > 1);
% Loop *backwards* through indices (so they don't shift up by 1 as we go)
for ii = numel(idx):-1:1
    x = insertNaN(x,idx(ii));
    y = insertNaN(y,idx(ii));
end
% Plot appears the same as the second plot above
plot(x,y);
```

**Note:** If you want to do further processing on `x` and `y`, it might not be best to add random `NaN` values into the array! You can either:

- Remove them afterwards (assuming there weren't pre-existing NaNs)

  ```
  x = x(~isnan(x));
  y = y(~isnan(y));
  ```
- Use temporary variables for plotting

  ```
   xplot = x;
   % then adding NaNs to xplot for plotting ...
  ```

Comment: I have applied this method while using the tolerance of 10^6 only when the function runs however the connecting line is still present? My x values are quite a long list of data and so are my y values. Would this by why it may not be working with my data? if so, what changes can I make?

Comment: The length of your vectors will make no difference. Have you actually looked at the x values (using the data cursor in the plot even) to determine what your jump tolerance should actually be? Without seeing a relevant sample of your data, I could not say if 10^6 is suitable, I was just guessing!

Comment: x = [1415890679 1415890689 1415890699 1415890709 1415890719 1415890729 1415890740 1416409500 1416409509 1416409519 ];

y = [13 13 12 14 14 15 13 12 13 15];

Using the 10^4 tolerance value does work when I've reduced the data down to two pairs as shown above.. however as shown on the question it self my data is not just two but many. And it doesn't seem to work when I run it on my whole data.

Is there any changes I can make to correct this?

Comment: The "jumps" in my data are not consistent. Thought I'd add that aswell to make it clearer. Thanks

Comment: The jumps don't have to be consistent, as long as they are all larger than the tolerance you choose. Just choose a tolerance of like 100 and see what the plot looks like, worst case scenario you'll plot actual continuous regions separately which isn't that bad... Which method above are you even trying to implement?

Comment: I have tried both but only works on two sets of data only. I tried setting the tol to 100 but still no changes.

Comment: My example literally uses 3 blocks... you need to debug your code, step through the method 1 plotting loop for example and see what gets plotted at each loop, and what the values of `idx` are.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152243/discussion-between-sajin-gurung-and-wolfie).